# Как выбрать конкретную колонку в grid css

Tags: css-grid

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно обратиться к конкретной колонке грида? (чтобы например задать ему бордер)
К элементам в сетке обращаемся типа .my_grid > a:nth-child(2), а вот можно ли обратиться к колонке или строке подобным образом?!

Comment: Нет нельзя, но вы можете всё ещё просчитывать по элементам. Например у вас идёт по 3 элемента в ряд и вы хотите применить стили только к последним элементам в каждой строке, получается вам нужно сделать - :nth-child(3n). буква "n" здесь играет роль инкремента типа "i++". 3*0, потом 3*1, 3*2 и так далее.

Answer (score 0):

Все конечно зависит от условий, иногда можно что-то сделать, иногда нет. Вот пример как можно сделать выделение колонок, но сложность в том, что  добавится строка или колонка и все нужно пересчитывать, а `css-переменные` тут работать не будут, генерировать `css правила`, можно, но не всем это понравится, хотя если страница генерируется `php` к примеру или каким-нибудь `js` фреймворком это решить можно гораздо проще — например `инлайн стилями` или `дата-аттрибутами` содержащими номер столбца и номер колонки.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  width: fit-content;
  background: #a2a5a5;
  color: black;
}
.wrapper div {
  padding: 5px; /* отступы от краев */
}

/* первая колонка в красной рамке */
.wrapper div:nth-child(3n + 1) {
  border-width: 0px 3px 0 3px; 
  border-color: red; 
  border-style: solid;
  background: rgba(255,0,0, .2);
}
 /* верхняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(1) {
  font-weight: bold;
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px; 
}
/* нижняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(7) {
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 3px; 
}

/* вторая колонка в зеленой рамке */
.wrapper div:nth-child(3n + 2) {
  border-width: 0px 3px 0 3px; 
  border-color: green; 
  border-style: solid;
  background: rgba(0,255, 0,.2);
}
 /* верхняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(2) {
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* нижняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(8) {
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 3px; 
}

/* третья колонка в голубой рамке */
.wrapper div:nth-child(3n) {
  border-width: 0px 3px 0 3px; 
  border-color: blue; 
  border-style: solid;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255,.2);
}
 /* верхняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(3) {
  border-width: 3px 3px 0 3px; 
  font-weight: bold;
}
/* нижняя ячейка */
.wrapper div:nth-child(9) {
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 3px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div>Фамилия</div>
   <div>Имя</div>
   <div>Отчество</div>
   <div>Иванов</div>
   <div>Иван</div>
   <div>Иваныч</div>
   <div>Сидоров</div>
   <div>Сидр</div>
   <div>Сидорович</div>
</div>
```